# Reading voltage on flyback diode's anode

Tags: voltage, diodes, flyback, schottky

So I have this motor driver that I've already asked a couple dozen questions about that I have finally got around to building.

Here's the final schematic that I'm using:

[image]

It uses only N channel MOSFETs. Reverse works by flipping both relays and reversing the voltage on the `MP` (Motor Positive) and `MN` (Motor Negative) path. It has a limitation where direction can only be reversed if the motor is not running, but that is acceptable for my purpose.

It probably will not come as a surprise to you when I tell you I blew it up.

Rookie mistake: I wanted to try testing the relay part of the circuit, forgetting the `DRIVE_PWM` line is pulled down on my micro controller side and having it disconnected. Apparently I assumed (and did not check) that the line would be low, thus the MOSFETs would be open. That was definitely not the case when the input was floating and I'm guessing the switching of the relays was not perfectly synchronous, so in the small window where one relay was switched and the other was not there was a path from `36V` to `GND`, and even though I had a 30A fuse on the positive line, one of my MOSFETs was faster to blow up.

After this event had happened I measured 36V on the `SO` line, which meant all 4 FETs were fried as well as my TC4420 driver. I was reading weird voltages all over the place so I went ahead and unsoldered all connections then replaced the driver IC and started soldering connections 1 by 1 checking and verifying voltages after each. I was being smart*er* this time - I added only 1 MOSFET and I had all connections made except the flyback diodes. I connected an LED with a 3k ohm resistor to `MP-MN` and verified varying `DRIVE_PWM` is working correctly, as well as flipping the direction.

I'm at the final step now and here's where I'm having my doubts. I have connected the `36V` side of `D1` and `D3` and I have both of their `VRL` sides still disconnected. When I measure across their `VRL` and `GND` I get 26V and 31V. I powered off the circuit and using the diode setting on my meter I read .126V and .153V

I'm not sure if I have done damage to the diodes or they are still usable. This may look like nothing to someone with more experience but is quite a bunch of work for me which I'd really love to not have to do one more time...

Note: `GND` and `GN2` are basically the same, I just use different labels so I can use different track widths in PCB design.

Comment: I suspect you would solve several problems just by using wires instead of net names to connect things. Offhand I don't see a connection between GND/GN2, a connector for 10V, GND, signals, well anything besides P1; why MOSFETs and diodes in parallel; etc. It seems like these were meant to connect to different things but they're all just glommed together and it's not clear if that was by intent or accident.

Comment: You said "final schematic" but it sounds like there is more. Can you show it all?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes you are correct, GND and GN2 are connected, and there is 10V connector, but they are missing from the screenshot. MOSFETs and diodes are not in parallel, or so I think. Diodes are parallel to the motor (`MP`, `MN`) via `VRL` and `36V`

Comment: Layout and probably waveforms would also be illuminating.

Comment: @TimWilliams well there's a reason these things are missing, it's like 30% dead-bug, the 10V comes from a buck converter that's powered from the 36V, and GND and GN2 are just soldered together, as I added to the question, the only reason there are 2 labels is if I eventually turn it into a PCB to be able to have different track widths. That's pretty much everything that's missing from the schematic.

Comment: FYI, a PCB cannot have multiple net names per net by default; you at least need a jumper ("net bridge") between them, which will be shown on the schematic. Trace widths are usually simply selected from an allowed range, or you can configure subnets if you really must use the autorouter (but this looks trivial enough the setup would take much longer than manual layout).

Comment: @TimWilliams you are most likely correct, it's just something I tried to do to help myself in the future, didn't intend it to end up on here and confuse people. I'm not really concerned with those things right now as I'm not even certain I'll get to making PCBs out of this, I'm just trying to get it to work first at this point.

Comment: You must remember that when using two relays, one will always switch later than the other.  You might consider using just one DPDT relay instead of two SPDT's to solve this issue.  However, it is generally a bad idea to use relays to switch inductive loads because of the tendency of arcing.  I know you could theoretically not allow switching when the motor is running, but if you lose power with a spinning motor, you could damage this circuit.  You might consider using an h-bridge instead; at this voltage you could use p-channel MOSFETs for the high side.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead normally the relays will be powered off 99% of the time. The motor will reverse fairly rarely and the event of losing power in these exact moments is quite low (although it will probably happen now when I have said that). This is just something that I've wanted to do for a very long time, definitely not the best design.

Comment: What's your motor current?

Comment: It is rated at 28A, but startup should be somewhere in the 10A range, I can only measure using an amp meter which is quite slow but it reads 6A on start up and then 1.5A when running with no load. It is [MY1020](https://www.motiondynamics.com.au/unite-my1020-36v-800w-3000-rpm-28.5a.html).